# Installation of dual stack k8s cluster on node with only IPv6 network

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I am trying to understand if it is possible to install a dual stack k8s cluster on nodes with only IPv6 network. Nodes don't have any IPv4 addressing. I am using kubespray to install k8s cluster but since kubespray does not support installing pure ipv6 cluster, i am trying to analyse what changes are needed to make kubespray install k8s cluster on nodes that have only IPv6 addresses